# 9V and 12V adaptors - bad output

Tags: current, dc, output, adapter

I have a couple 9V and 12V adapters ranging from 1A to 5A.

When I plug any one of them in, it produces accurate voltage but the current oscillates between 0A and anything up to maximum current and then back to 0A with about one second interval and the process continues.

I mean, if I use the 9V 2A adapter, the voltage will be around 9V but the current will be like:
`0A - 0.5A - 0A` then again `0A - 1A - 0A`. There is no proper current output.

I changed all of the capacitors but the output current is still bad.

Note: These are all factory assembled adapters so components are different for almost every adapter I have.

NetGear 12v 2.5A Adapter
[image: NetGear 12v 2.5A Adapter]

Comment: What load are you using?

Comment: how are you measuring the output current?

Comment: through Clamp meter

Comment: What is your job title or job specification?

Comment: @Andyaka: I'm basically IT guy but I've some experience with ELT so you can say it's hobby thing.

Comment: Just checking that you knew how to use a clamp meter and you knew how to load a power supply correctly.

Comment: Please show us a photo of your measuring setup. Include the adapter, your load, your meter, and how things are connected.

Comment: @marcelm: The setup is alright as when I use a newer 9v or 12v adapter and try to run the setup again accordingly, everything works flawlessly fine.

Comment: Which capacitors you changed? There's at least dozen of capacitors that have not been changed. Did you mean to say e.g. "all the electrolytic capacitors" instead?

Answer (score 2):

On a regulated adapter, presumably what you have, the output voltage specification is a **nominal output voltage** for any load within the normal range of operation (usually starting from zero).

The output current specification is a **maximum**. If you connect the adapter output across an ammeter you are basically shorting it and it will try to protect itself, often by turning on and off.

So, (virtually) constant output voltage for any load up to the maximum current rating. If you want a constant current you have to add a circuit to it, or use a switching circuit that is designed to provide a constant current (such as an LED driver circuit).

---

Here is the typical current draw waveform of a brushless DC fan from [here](https://www.newark.com/pdfs/techarticles/mro/DCBrushlessCoolingFanBehavior.pdf). The peak is around double the RMS, let alone the average:

[image]

You may need an adapter rated at 2-3x the average current, depending on the design of the adapter and how the overload protection is triggered. This same problem comes up frequently here when people try to run compressors and such like off of inverters or regulated supplies. The interaction of peak current in the load and limiting is not really covered by the datasheet and if you were designing a mass market product from scratch you would probably want to interact with the supplier to ensure it would work reliably under all conditions.

For onesy-twosie you may as well just buy a higher rated adapter and be done with it.

Comment: I'm plugging adapters to my old DC Computer Chasis FANs and measuring current via Clamp meter so there is no Short-Circuit, I guess.

Comment: Overload will have the same effect

Comment: For 9v, I'm testing it on my old Router rating **9v 1a** and for 12, I'm using Computer chasis FAN rating **12v 1.6a**. Both of my LOADs are lower in rating, thus no Overload.

Comment: Well, maybe they don't produce the nameplate current reliably. Are they of a reliable brand name? Not uncommon for no-name adapters to have 'optimistic' ratings, for example, they meet specs on 240VAC but not at 110VAC.

Comment: To name them, these are from **NetGear, Mercury, Tenda** and 2-3 local adapters and all are running on ~220VAC as prescribed.

Comment: Brushless fans have a fair bit of current ripple and startup surge that can greatly exceed the PSU rating. Resistors would be a much better test load.

Comment: I'm looking for (guesses on) faulty component(s). Other things like *Test Load* or *Measuring Instruments* etc are not the issue and irrelevant at this point.

Comment: Only the emitter/source current measuring resistor value, but it should look overheated, so it should have been noticed immediately.

Comment: I'd feel much more comfortable saying all of these supplies are junk, if they were ran into an electronic load (more test equipment.) "Fans" and other consumer devices can behave very non-linearly.

Comment: @rdtsc I agree 100%. Resistors or an electronic load would give consistent results, not loads like motors.

Comment: @rdtsc: I agree but I've to run those "Consumer Devices" on these adapters.

Comment: @ElT_Tech I'd say just get a different adapter. These things are pretty standard and you can find good ones that aren't too expensive from companies like Meanwell or something.